# Why I can't see my props from backend in my nuxt page?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-props

I'm making an index page nad I have to recover from my db customers data and insert it in a table element in my index page.
I've set my props, mounted function with axios that get the data from the backend route and in a data function I return customers array,

my index.vue page:

```html
<template>
  <div>
     <table v-if="customers">
  <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>address</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{{ customers.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ customers.address }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Table from "../components/Table.vue";
export default {
  components: { Table },
  name: "IndexPage",
  data() {
    return {
      customers: [],
    };
  },
  props: {
    customer: {
      required: true,
      type: Object,
    },
  },
  async mounted() {
    const response = await this.$axios.$get("/api/customers");
    this.customers = response.data;
  },
};
</script>
```

if I write {{ customers }} the function return the list of customers fields but when I search for a specific data (for example {{ customers.name }}) it don't return me nothing, even errors.

Obviously I've set baseurl in nuxt.config with address of my laravel app

Comment: Do you receive what you expect in the network tab?

Comment: @kissu probably yes

Comment: It's a yes or a no haha, probably is not a valid answer. You probably don't need the `customer` prop. You're using the `$get` shortcut here, so `.data` is not needed when fetching the customers. Also, you're using `table` as a component name which is a pretty bad idea because it conflicts with the native one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table You also don't need to import the components yourself since you're using Nuxt here. Change the name of the component to something like `MyComponent.vue` and use it directly into your template. Use `asyncData` or `fetch` too.

Comment: Regarding your issues, `customers.name` will indeed not returning anything because it's an array. It should rather be `customers[0].name` or something using `v-for` so that you can iterate on it efficiently. Use your Vue devtools for debugging purposes, it will be more efficient. A proper indentation (with Prettier) + some linting (with ESlint) may also help spotting bugs faster.